# spritekit 2 bodies collide but don't bounce off each other

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have 2 physics bodies in a scene. One of these bodies is a box that is just falling straight down (due to gravity), the other is a player that can stand, run, or jump while on the box.

Currently, when the player collides with the falling box, they bounce off each other, however, I don't want them to do that, I want the box and the player to not affect each other's physical movements, but just for the player to be able to stand, run and jump while he is on the box.

heres the code for both sprites:

```
func setUpPlayer() {
        player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: player.size)
        player.physicsBody?.mass = 1
        player.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
        player.xScale = 0.5
        player.yScale = 0.5
        player.position = CGPoint(x: 600, y: 800)
        addChild(player)
    }

func addSquare() {
        let squareNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "fblogo.png")

        squareNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: squareNode.size)
        squareNode.physicsBody?.mass = 1
        squareNode.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.2
        squareNode.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
        squareNode.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
        squareNode.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        squareNode.xScale = 0.5
        squareNode.yScale = 0.5
        squareNode.position = CGPoint(x: 500, y: 700)
        self.addChild(squareNode)
        squaresArray.addObject(squareNode)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting their physicsBody.collisionBitMask to be something nil. Maybe you could do merely 0:

```
func setUpPlayer() {
        player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: player.size)
        player.physicsBody?.mass = 1
        player.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
        player.xScale = 0.5
        player.yScale = 0.5
        player.position = CGPoint(x: 600, y: 800)
        addChild(player)
    }

func addSquare() {
        let squareNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "fblogo.png")

        squareNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: squareNode.size)
        squareNode.physicsBody?.mass = 1
        squareNode.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.2
        squareNode.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
        squareNode.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
        squareNode.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        squareNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        squareNode.xScale = 0.5
        squareNode.yScale = 0.5
        squareNode.position = CGPoint(x: 500, y: 700)
        self.addChild(squareNode)
        squaresArray.addObject(squareNode)
    }
```

This may not be ***exactly*** what you need, since I didn't put this into Xcode before posting this, to check if it works. But setting the collisionBitMask on an object means it only "bumps into" or "collides" with the objects with the BitMask of the passed in UInt or variable. That way, it's still dynamic, but not physically affected by the collision.